# Inner for loop time complexity

Tags: c++, big-o

```
int value2= 0;
int value1=0;
for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    for (int j = i; j < A.size(); j++) {
        value2 = 0;
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
            value2 += A[k];
        if (value2 > value1)
            value1 = value2;
    }



q=clock()-q;

cout << "Total Time: "<< ((float)q)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<"\n";
cout <<"Result: " << value1 <<"\n";
```

I went through and calculated the relational math for these nested loops but I am really confused about what the complexity for the 2nd and 3rd loops would be. My first thought was that the 2nd is n-1 and the third is just n because of the k <= j but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: If all you care about is Big O, then they're all N because the constants don't matter. If you want specific operation counts, then you'll end up doing some triangular number calculations since the inner loop depends on the outer one in a linear way.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I think I do? I'm not 100% sure. I know that it does matter if it is n - 1 or just n because then the relational math would be easier to do, but I don't think I should be having as much trouble as I am at this point. sorry for not be specific about what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation is used to express a "bound". so, call `A.size()` to `n`, it can be `O(n^3)` in Big-O notation.

or more strictly, the first and second loops are `O(n^2)` because the sum of count is `n + (n-1) + ... + (n - (n - 1)) = n*(n+1)/2`. - (a)

the third one gets affected by only `i`, and `j`. Let's count how many interval `[i, j]` is in.

the length of `[i, j]` can assume to `n` in Big-O's view. - (b)

therefore (a) * (b) is `O( (n*(n+1)/2) * n ) = O(n^3)`.

In summary (on the other way), count it all.

there are `n` intervals which size is `1` as like: `[0, 0], [1, 1], ..., [n, n]`
there are `n-1` intervals which size is `2` as like: `[0, 1], [1, 2], ..., [n-1, n]`
...
there are only `1` intervals which size is `n` as like: `[n, n]` when `i=0, j=n-1`.

thus, `n*1 + (n-1)*2 + ... + 1*n = (n-1)*n*(n+1) / 6` is for all loop.

The Big-O notation is `O(n^3)`

Comment: O(n^3) overall is correct but the statement mentioning O(n^1.5) is wrong.

Comment: @MoB.Oh you're right. why am i write 1.5 lol.. my bad, i edited it.